# Java. Object references

Tags: java, android

Q1: AT line 5, will `mess` loose the reference to the object instantiated on line 1 (get overridden)?

Q2: On line 3 in the `enqueue` method I store the reference of mess in a new "slot" of an `ArrayList`. Even if the reference to the object created on line 1 will be lost (because of line 5), it won't be garbage collected because the `ArrayList` still points to it?

Q3: after the execution of these 7 lines, in the queue of the controller there should be 2 references to the two `Messenger` objects?

```
1: Messenger mess = new Messenger(_TYPE1_);
2: /* ... */
3: controller.enqueue(mess); // store the reference inside a Runnable in the queue
4: /* ... */
5: mess = new Messenger(_TYPE2_);
6: /* ... */
7: controller.enqueue(mess);
```

Comment: Voted to close, as no real question. BTW, the answer is yes. But please refrain from asking rhetorical questions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A1: Yes, it will lose the reference. The value of that reference (you can see it as a pointer) will be overwritten with the reference of the new `Message` object. In short: `mess` stops "pointing" at `_TYPE1_` and now "points" at `_TYPE2_`.

A2: By definition, an object is eligible for Garbage Collection if there are no references pointing at him. You've answered your own question here.

A3: Yes, since the objects you queued were different (different objects referenced at queueing time).

Answer (score 1):

Q1 : Yes, it just gets reassigned with a new reference.

Q2 : Right.

Q3 : Right.